# A way to get location coordinates from command line

Tags: adb, geolocation

I'm looking for a command line, or a series of commands that can dump or list the latitude and longitude on a rooted device.

I connect to a device using ADB shell.
A way that will cause the coordinates to be logged to the command line is also good for me.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Looks like there is a way:

> adb shell dumpsys location > dumpsys.txt

This will give you a file with all location service information. In this file search for `'Last Known Locations'` and you should see something like:

```
passive: Location[network 92.915479,55.610965 acc=22 et=+1d4h10m34s255ms {Bundle[{noGPSLocation=Location[network 92.915479,55.610965 acc=22 et=+1d4h10m34s255ms {Bundle[{coarseLocation=Location[network 92.918919,55.603997 acc=2000 et=+1d4h10m34s255ms]}]}], networkLocationSource=cached, networkLocationType=wifi, travelState=stationary}]}]

network: Location[network 92.915479,55.610965 acc=22 et=+1d4h10m34s255ms {Bundle[{noGPSLocation=Location[network 92.915479,55.610965 acc=22 et=+1d4h10m34s255ms {Bundle[{coarseLocation=Location[network 92.918919,55.603997 acc=2000 et=+1d4h10m34s255ms]}]}], networkLocationSource=cached, networkLocationType=wifi, travelState=stationary}]}]
```

Of course, the list will include another entry if you have the GPS provider enabled on the device.

Going by android code, I tried to find out how apps get the location when they use LocationManager.getLastKnownLocation(). After a bit of following, I ended up in LocationManagerService [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.4.4_r1/com/android/server/LocationManagerService.java?av=h#LocationManagerService). which implements getLastLocation and also a dump function.

The coordinates are not stored in any file as far as I can tell. They are stored in memory in a hashmap and dumped for the dumpsys command. This also explains why a directory heirarchy search did not reveal any files with gps info.

If you want this info in a more standard format, you will need to take the app route and go with something like [this](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mendhak.gpslogger&hl=en). This app exports the info in a GPS or a KML file that you can feed into geo based apps.

PS: This works on non-rooted device just as well.

Comment: For Windows user: `adb shell dumpsys location > dumpsys.txt` to output the result to the file.

Comment: I try to detect **GPS status (active, passive)** through the emulator using `adb shell`, the `Last Known Locations` info is always empty even I manually enable GPS.

Comment: Or on Windows if you're using PowerShell like you should be: **adb shell dumpsys location | Out-File location.txt**